# How can I update my state before rendering render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I simply want my render method code run after update state in `useEffect`.

I store my token in `asyncStorage` and now I want if token exist then it redirect at `homePage` else return at `loginPage`. But problem is that render method run before updating my state in `useEffect`. And it keeps me on `loginPage` even I had token.

My code Is below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { useLinkProps, useNavigation, CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

import MainScreen from './src/screens/MainScreen';
import SignIn from './src/screens/SignIn';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = props => {

  const [isSigned, setIsSigned] = useState(false);

  useEffect(async () => {
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@token");

    console.log("token", token);

    if (token) {
      setIsSigned(true);
      props.navigation.navigate('MainScreen');
    }
    else {
      setIsSigned(false);
      props.navigation.navigate('SignIn');
    }
  }, [])


  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={isSigned ? "MainScreen" : "SignIn"}
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={SignIn} />
        <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={MainScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: Platform.OS === 'android' ? '3%' : '10%'
  }
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add another state value to conditionally render your markup:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import { useLinkProps, useNavigation, CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

import MainScreen from './src/screens/MainScreen';
import SignIn from './src/screens/SignIn';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = props => {
  // Manage state whether component has been loaded.
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [isSigned, setIsSigned] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@token");
    
    if (token) {
      setIsSigned(true);
      props.navigation.navigate('MainScreen');
    } else {
      setIsSigned(false);
      props.navigation.navigate('SignIn');
    }

    // Tell your component it's been loaded.
    setIsLoaded(true);
  }, []);

  // Don't render if not loaded.
  if (!isLoaded) return <></>;

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName={isSigned ? "MainScreen" : "SignIn"}
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={SignIn} />
        <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={MainScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: above solution doesn't work. it shows black screen.